# how to remove new lines in sublime text using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a text/csv file that looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to remove all the blank new lines. How can I do so? 
I tried using regex with matching \n, but then this would merge all the lines into one line.

Comment: maybe you can use this site,no is with sublime text but is a option http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press `ctrl + shift + f`

[image]

and Replace "\n\n" to "\n"
[image]

Comment: seemed to do the job well

Answer (score 8):

```
^[\s]*\n
```

you can use that, if you elaborate a bit more I could help you to find a more accurate regular expression
with this you should get any line with blank characters,

cheers

Answer (score 2):

For sublime replace[ctrl+alt+f]
use regex  `\n`
replace with `<nothing>`